# Java Two Dimensional Array (Grabbing only odd columns issue)

Tags: java, arrays

I had to create a 10x10 array and multiply each col and row, this wasn't a problem. However, I need help on how to grab only the odd columns and print a total, as well as the even. My java is only entry level so I can better understand it explain if possible.

```
class multiplyArray
{
        private static final int tableSize = 10;
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
                int table[][] = new int [tableSize][tableSize];
                for (int r=1; r<=10; r++)
                {
                        for (int c=1; c<=10; c++)
                        {
                                System.out.printf(r*c+"\t");
                        }
                        System.out.println();
                }
        }
}

class oddArray
{
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
                int table[][] = new int [10][10];
                for (int r=0; r<table.length; r++)
                {
                        int total = 0;
                        for (int c=1; c<=table[r].length; c+=2)
                        {
                                System.out.printf(r*c+"\t");
                                total+= table[c][r];
                        }
                        System.out.println();
                        System.out.println(total);
                }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can *increment* column by `2` instead of `1` in for *loop* * (i.e `c += 2`) which will provide you only `odd` *columns* of every *rows*, as you have already started the inner loop from `1` which is needed in case of odd columns but for outer loop you have to start it with `0` because array index starts with `0` not `1`. Moreover, declare one `total` variable to add all *odd* column values to it in  loop. One thing to add change condition in loop to `r < table.length` and `c < table[r].length`

<sub>* Assuming you have inserted values in array, you can have c += 2 instead of c++ in loop.</sub>

Comment: Edited with what you said but i'm actually getting even number now?

Comment: @Danny that's because you started with `c=2`. Try starting with `c=1`.

Comment: Perfect, thank you @patstuart I created a total variable to add up all the odd columns and created total += tablesize[c][r] but it's spitting out the error: cannot find symbol?

Comment: @Danny that's because you want `tableSize`, not `tablesize`. :)

Comment: @patstuart man this case sensitivity haha, corrected. Following error given now though: array required, but int found?

Comment: @Danny I recommend an IDE like Eclipse to help you step through the code in debug mode. This way you can see the variable through every step of the program. There are several good tutorials on Google.